# Distributing both identical and distinct objects

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute 7 **distinct** apples and 11 **identical** oranges to two different baskets so that each basket gets at least one apple and at least one orange?

My Answer + Reasoning: 
Give each an orange, and there are ${10 \choose 9}$ ways of distributing the rest.
Give each an apple which can be done ${7 \choose 2}$ ways, then the rest can be distributed in $2^5$ ways. 
 Thus, answer is ${10 \choose 9}$ * ${7 \choose 2}$ * $2^5$ = 6720 ways.

Can someone double check this? I am a bit unsure about the distinct apples part.

Comment: just think about the apples.  Since they are distinct there must be $2^7$ ways to distribute them (ignoring the restriction that each basket gets at least one).  How many ways are there in which one basket gets no apples?

Comment: So, would it just be 2^7 ways minus the two outcomes where one basket gets all of them? So, C(10, 9) * 126?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.